# DataTable order por Data pt-br

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Estou utilizando o componente 
[DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/) versão 1.19 e estou com problemas para ordenar por data no padrão `DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss`

já tentei com moment, data-eu e nada faz ele ficar corretamente ordenado

Fiz um exemplo no fiddle.net
https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/zn1vg3at/12/

O melhor que consegui foi ordenar por data porém o Id se perde.
https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/zn1vg3at/19/

No StackOverflow-en teve algumas sugestões bizarras como colocar um timestamp oculto e ordernar por ele. O que pra mim é uma enorme gambiarra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma é colocando um atributo `data-order` ([veja documentação](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)) em cada `td` da coluna que você quer ordenar. O valor desse atributo deve ter o formato "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS".

Por exemplo:

```
<td data-order="2020/04/02 14:48:37">
   02/04/2020 14:48:37
</td>
```

O Datatables trabalha com esse atributo e ordena pelo seu valor em vez do que tem na célula.

No exemplo abaixo eu coloquei dentro da primeira coluna de cada linha um número que indica a ordem correta. Faça o teste e veja que os números da primeira coluna ficam na sequência correta de acordo com a data da segunda coluna, na ordem escolhida:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    $('table').DataTable({
        "order": [
            [1, "desc"]
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="TabelaListas" class="table table-hover dataTable table-striped table-bordered no-footer" >
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Data Cadastro</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
  
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
            2
         </td>
   <td data-order="2020/01/04 14:49:24">
            01/04/2020 14:49:24
         </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
            3
         </td>
         <td data-order="2020/04/02 14:48:37">
            02/04/2020 14:48:37
         </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
            4
         </td>
   <td data-order="2020/05/01 14:25:01">
            01/05/2020 14:25:01
         </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
            1
         </td>
   <td data-order="2020/01/01 14:25:01">
            01/01/2020 14:25:01
         </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
            6
         </td>
   <td data-order="2020/07/01 14:25:02">
            02/07/2020 14:25:02
         </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
            5
         </td>
   <td data-order="2020/05/01 14:25:02">
            01/05/2020 14:25:02
         </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Neste caso, se estiver usando Moment.js apenas para isso, não precisa mais carregá-lo.

Comment: meio gambiarra né? existe algum componente mais moderno no lugar do datatable.net?

Comment: Não é gambiarra não. Tá na [documentação](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) do componente.

Comment: mas parece que foi o modo que eles fizeram para fazer funcionar..rs mas de qualquer maneira deu certo!